# How can I ask mysql to create the database?

Tags: mysql

I'm running the command :

```
mysql --user=root --password=root --port=3306 --host=localhost my_db < my_db_backup.sql
```

But I get the error `ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database`. How can I ask mysql to create the database if it doesn't exist ? I don't want the database name to be in the .sql file, I need to be able to restore the backup's contents in different databases.

Comment: Why not use `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS`, as usual? Is this problem even related to programming?

Comment: @NicoHaase I specifically mentioned why in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use the `--one-database` flag along with the `--database` flag in your command, so you don't need to include the database name in the `.sql` file and this allows you to restore the backup's contents in different databases as needed!

check this out :

```
mysql --user=root --password=root --port=3306 --host=localhost --execute="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_db;" && mysql --user=root --password=root --port=3306 --host=localhost my_db < my_db_backup.sql
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem that the database isn't created :/

Comment: Yeah, I had thought about doing that (although I didn't know about the --execute command, where is the doc for that ? I tried finding it on the mysql website but couldn't), but I was hoping a simple option like --create-db-if-not-exists :')

Comment: Yeah, I finally found the command list and while --init-command looked good, it seems to be ignored in this case. Guess I won't find anything better

Comment: For reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_init-command